# Error while importing Kaggle dataset on Colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, valueerror, kaggle

When executing the following lines,

```
!pip install kaggle
!kaggle competitions download -c dogs-vs-cats -p /content/
```

I got the following error messages,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/kaggle", line 7, in <module>
from kaggle.cli import main
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/kaggle/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
api.authenticate()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/kaggle/api/kaggle_api_extended.py", line 109, in authenticate
self._load_config(config_data)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/kaggle/api/kaggle_api_extended.py", line 151, in _load_config
raise ValueError('Error: Missing %s in configuration.' % item)
ValueError: Error: Missing username in configuration.
```

I don't know what just happened...same lines just worked fine before. It's the first time I found this problem.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It suddenly stopped working here as well. Apparently, the kaggle api was not searching the kaggle.json file in the correct place.
Since I was using the kaggle api inside a colab notebook, I was importing the kaggle.json like this:

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
import io, os
from googleapiclient.http import MediaIoBaseDownload
from google.colab import auth

auth.authenticate_user()

drive_service = build('drive', 'v3')
results = drive_service.files().list(
        q="name = 'kaggle.json'", fields="files(id)").execute()
kaggle_api_key = results.get('files', [])

filename = "/content/.kaggle/kaggle.json"
os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(filename), exist_ok=True)

request = drive_service.files().get_media(fileId=kaggle_api_key[0]['id'])
fh = io.FileIO(filename, 'wb')
downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(fh, request)
done = False
while done is False:
    status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
    print("Download %d%%." % int(status.progress() * 100))
os.chmod(filename, 600)
```

It worked just fine. But now, the kaggle api searches the kaggle.json in this location:

```
~/.kaggle/kaggle.json
```

So, I just had to move/copy the file I downloaded to the right place:

```
!mkdir ~/.kaggle
!cp /content/.kaggle/kaggle.json ~/.kaggle/kaggle.json
```

And it started working again.

Comment: Yes, we had been setting `$HOME=/content` for historical reasons, but recently undid that.

If you just use `filename = os.path.expanduser("~/.kaggle/kaggle.json")` in the snippet above, you shouldn't need to do the extra copy (since I'm guessing you only need the file in one place).

Answer (score 10):

This simple thing did it for me on Google Cola.

```
!echo '{"username":"USERNAME","key":"KEY"}' > ~/.kaggle/kaggle.json
!kaggle datasets download -d mmoreaux/environmental-sound-classification-50
```

--

edit, might have changed to:

```
!echo '{"username":"USERNAME","key":"KEY"}' > /root/.kaggle/kaggle.json
!kaggle datasets download -d mmoreaux/environmental-sound-classification-50
```

Comment: Thanks for me it did only work if I choose the following direcotry.
!echo '{"username":"USERNAME","key":"KEY"}' > /root/.kaggle/kaggle.json

Answer (score 3):

Initially had trouble copying the .json file into the colab VM. Eventually for me the following worked: 
working through google colaboratory, first you need to install the kaggle API with:

```
!pip install kaggle
```

Further information and instructions here https://github.com/Kaggle/kaggle-api.
Next, the link instructs you to activate the API with a file you can download with your kaggle user on *kaggle.com -> My account -> create new API token*. this file is *kaggle.json*.

Next, in order to upload this *kaggle.json* file to the colab VM for activation, you can upload it first to your google drive (simply drag it to your drive). Next enter the following command in colab to import your drive:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
```

after authorization is completed, you can copy the file from the drive to colab with:

```
!cp /content/gdrive/My\ Drive/kaggle.json ~/.kaggle/kaggle.json
```

And Finally, hopefully you will be able to run the command:

```
!kaggle competitions download -c <competition-name>
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Check the permissions on your `kaggle.json` file as well. I got the same error because after running a different a kaggle command, I got this warning:

> Warning: Your Kaggle API key is readable by other users on this system! To fix this, you can run 'chmod 600 /...etc/kaggle.json'

I ran what they suggested, and got the same error you did until I changed the permissions back to what they'd been before.

This is my own machine (the other user is a mentor I trust), so I used `chown 666 /.../kaggle.json` and that solved it, but be careful and only give permissions based on that make sense with your respective setup.

Answer (score 1):

`five` Easy steps:

Step 1: 
Import the drive

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
```

Get authorize code from `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=xxx` and enter the code at `Enter your authorization code:`

Step 2:
Download the kaggle.json file in the local system

> kaggle.com -> My account -> create

Step 3: 
Upload the `kaggle.json` file.
Click `>` at top left corner of Colab to get

> `panel` -> Files -> UPLOAD

Step 4:
Copy the file to Colab

```
!cp /your path/kaggle.json ~/.kaggle/kaggle.json
```

Step 5:
Fix Warning

> Your Kaggle API key is readable by other users on this system!

```
!chmod 600 /root/.kaggle/kaggle.json
```

TEST

```
!pip install kaggle
import kaggle
!kaggle competitions list --csv
```

RESULT

ref,deadline,category,reward,teamCount,userHasEntered
digit-recognizer,2030-01-01 00:00:00,Getting Started,Knowledge,2867,False
titanic,2030-01-01 00:00:00,Getting Started,Knowledge,11221,False
house-prices-advanced-regression-techniques,2030-01-01 00:00:00,Getting Started,Knowledge,4353,True
imagenet-object-localization-challenge,2029-12-31 07:00:00,Research,Knowledge,40,False
competitive-data-science-predict-future-sales,2019-12-31 23:59:00,Playground,Kudos,2780,False
two-sigma-financial-news,2019-07-15 23:59:00,Featured,"$100,000",2927,False
aerial-cactus-identification,2019-07-08 23:59:00,Playground,Knowledge,377,False
jigsaw-unintended-bias-in-toxicity-classification,2019-06-26 23:59:00,Featured,"$65,000",982,False
inaturalist-2019-fgvc6,2019-06-10 23:59:00,Research,Kudos,75,False
freesound-audio-tagging-2019,2019-06-10 11:59:00,Research,"$5,000",250,False

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the home directory in Colab changed recently from `/content` to `/root`. Using `~` in paths to refer to HOME rather than hard-coding `/content` will fix.

I've updated the step-by-step workflow in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50650918/8841057) to reflect the changes. Sorry for the trouble!

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll try this. Thank you for your kindness.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you installed kaggle api first: `pip install kaggle`.
Then grab your API tokens from https://www.kaggle.com/kaggle_user_name/account:
[image]

And just download your data for the competition (in here `dogs-vs-cats-redux-kernels-edition`)

```
! touch /root/.kaggle/kaggle.json
! chmod 600 /root/.kaggle/kaggle.json
! echo '{"username":"kaggle_user_name","key":"0000000000000000000000000000000000"}' >> /root/.kaggle/kaggle.json
! kaggle competitions download -c "dogs-vs-cats-redux-kernels-edition"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
What I tried to do is to change the location of my kaggle.json file to somewhere else.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).