# I'm trying to download the dataset for the kaggle competition twosigma

Tags: python-3.x

I have to do a project for my class based on the kaggle competition twosigma but the problem comes when I try to import my dataset from kaggle.competitions.
Can anyone help me?

This is the code I found:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time
import lightgbm as lgb
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error 
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

plt.style.use('seaborn')
sns.set(font_scale=2)

import warnings 
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
import os

from kaggle.competitions import twosigmanews
# You can only call make_env() once, so don't lose it!
env = twosigmanews.make_env()
print('Done!')
```

This is the error I have:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-25118fdba524> in <module>()
----> 1 from kaggle.competitions import twosigmanews
      2 # You can only call make_env() once, so don't lose it!
      3 env = twosigmanews.make_env()
      4 print('Done!')

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kaggle\__init__.py in <module>()
     21 
     22 api = KaggleApi(ApiClient())
---> 23 api.authenticate()

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kaggle\api\kaggle_api_extended.py in 
authenticate(self)
    108 
    109         # Step 3: load into configuration!
--> 110         self._load_config(config_data)
    111 
    112     def read_config_environment(self, config_data={}, quiet=False):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kaggle\api\kaggle_api_extended.py in 
_load_config(self, config_data)
    147         for item in [self.CONFIG_NAME_USER, self.CONFIG_NAME_KEY]:
    148             if item not in config_data:
--> 149                 raise ValueError('Error: Missing %s in 
configuration.' % item)
    150 
    151         configuration = Configuration()

ValueError: Error: Missing username in configuration.
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be related to the incorrect location of the Kaggle configuration file.

Also, check below related answer:

[Error while importing Kaggle dataset on Colab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51958553/error-while-importing-kaggle-dataset-on-colab)